# Non-Muslims and the Koran

Tags: non-muslim

Does the Koran give permission to kill Non-Muslims? Since I read so many reports of Muslims pressuring Christians to take down Christmas trees, destroying Buddhist monuments, Western cultural artifacts it seems that Islam will not tolerate anything that is not Islam. I read that many Non-Muslims are dying (being killed) because they will not give up faith in God that Muslims perceive as wrong. I wonder how the future of humanity will be if Muslims attack Non-Muslims. Where do aggressive Muslims get the right to attack Non-Muslims? Does this permission really exist within the Koran?

Answer (score -2):

Islam is a relgion of peace and invites everyone to be peaceful towards others.

There are 2 things we could say about it:

1. Nowadays the medias and politics of the non-Muslim countries can't tolerate the development of islam, so they persuade people that Islam is the religion of war, horror and fight. That's why first Alqaeda then Taleban and now Daesh is created by them to show a horror face of Islam that it never had. If you go deep into the logics of islam and read the holy Quran, its always mentioned to be peaceful and show kindness towards others and other religions.
2. If you really wanna know who are behind these things then you will never go to see what Muslims do. Instead you will search for what Islam says. 
   Check out Islam in Turkey, Indonesia, Malaysia and ... countries if you wanna see what muslims are doing.

And talking about Buddhists just as an example. See what have they have done to Muslims in Myanmar? Why isn't anyone taking any action about that? The same way others.
May god open your mind and show you the truth. And hope my words haven't hurt you.

Comment: You neither answered the question nor added references to your answer!

Comment: That wasnt a question that needs a lot of additional references.